# PHP hash() returns empty string... sometimes

Tags: php, hash, sha256

I have extremely annoying issues with the php hash() function. For some strings the returned hash is just an empty string, for others it works fine.

I wrote the following:

```
$new_salted_pw = $salt.$pepper.$new_pw; 
echo $new_salted_pw."... "; 
$hash = hash("sha256", $new_salted_pw);
if($hash>120)       
    $hash = substr($hash, 120);

echo $hash;
```

I used the passwords `geheim23` and `Geheim23` for testing, so only 1 character difference.

The result is:

`k0g3po32ggd0sv8oehgklbp2bd8eddxXMaxGTPJSQZSAJzgZSgaZxvUfGeheim23... d79e2044baa8a0a7363c88b4a2224277ac883eabc22cd28d61c1cdc31bb1c3fc`

`k0g3po32ggd0sv8oehgklbp2bd8eddxXMaxGTPJSQZSAJzgZSgaZxvUfgeheim23...`

No hash for the second one. It's empty. Same code, no result.

Even more interestingly, hashing `geheim23` in exactly the same way works in a different part of my script without problems.

And that's when I decided to ask Stackoverflow if it knows why PHP is doing this to me, how to fix it, or what function I could use instead of hash().

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the `hash()` function! The problem is in the `substr()` function. You have to change this:

(Here you started at the position 120, but you want the string form 0 to 120)

```
$hash = substr($hash, 120);
```

to:

```
$hash = substr($hash,0,  120);
```

Also i think you want to check if the length is longer that 120 and not if the hash value is bigger than 120 so change this:

```
if($hash>120)
```

to this:

```
if(strlen($hash) > 120)
```

For more information about `substr()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

And a quote from there:

> string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

Comment: Oh god, it worked. I'm so happy. I've been fighting with this for like a day. Thanks a lot, seriously. And thanks for the hints. Will accept in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for hashing/verifying passwords.

These functions are available in PHP > 5.5 but I don't know any reason why anyone should do a new project for older version.

Some point why you should use that:

- It's easy to use
- You don't care about salt
- It's made for hashing password (not like md5, sha*, etc.)